# unix: continue cp when error occurs?

Tags: unix, cygwin, cp

I have a directory with around 50,000 .jpg images.
Let's call this directory "imageDir", and the empty directory I'm trying to copy to "outputDir".

when I execute:

```
cp imageDir/* outputDir/
```

around 30,000ish images through I get:

```
cp: cannot open `imageDir/234235.jpg' for reading: Bad address
```

(this does not always occur on the same file) and then the copy operation will cease without copying the rest of the files.
I tried adding the `-R` option after reading that it would continue the copy even if errors occurred:

```
cp -R imageDir/* outputDir/
```

but this did nothing to solve my problem.

Is there some sort of limit to the number of files you can successfully copy at a time?
Why am I seeing this error, and how can I solve it? (if it happened for just photos here and there, I'd be fine with it as long as it completed the rest!)

Additionally: this is using Cygwin on Windows 7.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `rsync` has better error-handling options?

Comment: @cdhowie perhaps? I didn't know about rsync. What would the syntax be for this example?

Comment: The -R option to `cp` has nothing to do with error handling; it means that the contents of any subdirectories encountered will be recursively copied to the destination.

Comment: @JimLewis I'm aware but I ran into this page: http://ss64.com/osx/cp.html where it says "In -R mode, cp will continue copying even if errors are detected." However, I just realized that that might be for OSX only.

Comment: Tar will continue to archive/extract on error and is a golden standard for directory/partition replication on *nix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an issue with Cygwin to me. Since you said it happens randomly, you might just want to try again when it happens.  Here's a script (untested) that will do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in imageDir/*
do
  cp $i outputDir/
  while [ $? -ne 0 ]
  do
    cp $i outputDir/
  done
done
```

Comment: hmm..I appreciate the suggestion but it's excruciatingly slow. I didn't think it would be so sluggish..but I'll give you the answer if no one else comes up with something.

Comment: You could upvote my answer if it does indeed work, even if it's slow ;)

Comment: Probably a good idea to supply `-v` to `cp` so that you can see what's happening.  (Unless this is being run from cron, for example.)